# Excel legend (bring to front)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an excel chart which has a blue gradient image bar at the top behind the title and subtitle.

I want the legend to be in the top right but it automatically puts it underneath the blue bar and while the legend has no option for bringing to the front, the blue bar has the option to send to back but it does nothing and the legend still remains hidden

Any ideas?

Comment: See if these help: [link1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-a-chart-legend-or-data-table-5d663010-fee5-4953-a2ab-18f529543fd5) and [link2](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-color-coding-microsoft-excel-graph-legend-75610.html).

Comment: They sadly don’t help :(

Comment: One typical Excel workaround is to apply formatting to the spreadsheet behind the chart and using transparency on the chart to see behind it.  Combine that with layout snapping to grid and you can get well-aligned chart objects and cells, with the chart elements visually above the format.  If you can provide an image of what you're attempting, we can give you a better answer.